# read unicode from file and display text

Tags: java, android, unicode

how to read unicode characters from a file and display corresponding letters in a textview.For example the file contains the following

> \u0BAB\u0BCD\u0BAA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you started:

```
String str = "\\u0BAB\\u0BCD\\u0BAA";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i += 6) {
    String chStr = str.substring(i+2, i+6);
    sb.append((char) Integer.parseInt(chStr, 16));
}

System.out.println("Result: " + sb.toString());
```